# Download file to byte array using SSH.NET (VB.NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net, download, sftp, ssh.net

I would like to download a file from SFTP using the SSH.NET library. However, I would like this file to be received in `Byte` array. Thus, this file must be stored **in memory**.

Here's how I do it

```
Sub Main()
   Dim client As SftpClient = New SftpClient(hostname, username, password)
   client.Connect()
   Using b As System.IO.Stream = client.OpenRead("/www/Server.exe")
        Dim data() As Byte = GetStreamAsByteArray(b)
   End Using
End Sub

Public Shared Function GetStreamAsByteArray(ByVal stream As System.IO.Stream) As Byte()
    Dim streamLength As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length)

    Dim fileData As Byte() = New Byte(streamLength) {}

    ' Read the file into a byte array
    stream.Read(fileData, 0, streamLength)
    stream.Flush()
    stream.Close()

    Return fileData
End Function
```

However this method does not work: indeed, by writing it on the disk to test it, it is corrupted.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the only issue but how do you create an array?  Do you specify the length or the upper bound?

Comment: Are you sure the stream from client.OpenRead("/www/Server.exe") is valid?

Comment: How corrupted? Are some bytes modified? Is the file truncated? + Why do you even need byte array? Isn't `Stream` you get from `OpenRead` enough for most purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is imo more or less correct. The only problem is that, in VB.NET, the `New Byte(X)` does allocate an array one byte longer than you want: `0..X` (not `1..X` or `0..X-1` as you might have expected).

So if you then save the complete array (e.g. by `File.WriteAllBytes`) and not only `stream.Length` bytes, the file will be one byte larger, with an additional trailing NULL byte.

This is correct:

```
Dim fileData As Byte() = New Byte(streamLength - 1) {}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for spending time looking at my code! Yes indeed, I was convinced that my problem was a mishandling of SSH.NET, not the byte array ... I understand, the problem is finally quite sensitive, especially when handling a byte array. Anyway, thank you again for your help, you explain well!